# Bootstrap Nav Links out of order

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, haml

Not sure what I've done for this, but somehow my nav links are rendering out of order.

I'm working on a Rails project so all my code is in HAML.

This is my navigation bar code:

```
  .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
   .container
    .navbar-header
      %button{ :type => "button", :class => "navbar-toggle", "data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-target" => "navbar-collapse" }
       %span.sr-only
        Toggle Navigation
       %span.icon-bar
       %span.icon-bar
       %span.icon-bar

    .navbar-collapse.collapse
     %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
      =render 'layouts/navigation_links'
```

And then my links code:

```
%li =link_to "Home", root_path
%li =link_to "About", '/about'
%li =link_to "Products", '/products'
%li =link_to "Suppliers", '/suppliers'
%li =link_to "Let's Talk", '/contact'
```

And instead of rendering Home, About, Products, Suppliers, Let's Talk, it's doing the reverse order.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have 'float: right' or 'float: left' defined somewhere on the elements.

If you do, you can simply reverse the order that you list them in your 'navigation_links' code or you can remove the 'float' css rules.